# How to get google account name/email in Appcelerator

Tags: android, titanium, appcelerator, account

I'm trying to retrieve the username (or email) of the (default) Google account of the device. I've tried Ti.Platform.username, but that only gives me 'dpi', which of course doesn't make any sense.

Is there an easy way to retrieve this information?